# If I wanted to embed a live YouTube video on a webpage, how soon in advance could I get the embed code to that video?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

Say I wanted to stream a live video, I know I can go to YouTube, click the live button and grab the embed code BUT how soon could one get a live video and embed it into their site? If there was a news station like CNN or SkyNews for instance, could we get the embed code for the live broadcast one day in advance? One Week? Or do you just have to wait until the video starts playing live to get the embed code?

Comment: I believe they would have to setup the live stream video in advance.

Comment: How would a user go about getting that code in advance?

Comment: The user creating the live stream would need to setup in advance and make the link public. There may not be any way to find the stream ID without the user telling you.

Comment: Thank you for the input.